# Why Controller.UpdateModel doesn't validate model with globalized validation attributes from a unit test?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing

I created an ASP.NET MVC 5 application, with the following model class using a **globalized** Required validation attribute on its Email property:

```
public class Person
{
    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources),
              ErrorMessageResourceName = "EmptyEmailError")]
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

The Create POST action method of the PersonController class is:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(FormCollection formData)
{
    Person newPerson = new Person();
    UpdateModel(newPerson, formData);

    if (ModelState.IsValid) {
        // code to create the new person
        return View("Index", newPerson);
    }
    else {
        return View();
    }
}
```

And the test case for verifying that a person with an empty e-mail address is not created is:

```
[TestMethod]
void Create_DoesNotCreatePerson_WhenEmailIsEmpty()
{
    // arrange
    FormCollection person = new FormCollection() { { "Email", string.Empty } };
    PersonController controller = new PersonController();
    controller.ControllerContext = new ControllerContext();

    // act
    controller.Create(person);

    // assert
    Assert.IsFalse(controller.ModelState.IsValid);
}
```

With this code the normal execution works fine. However, the test doesn't pass, which means that `UpdateModel` is returning `true` and thus not validating the person model correctly. The `TryUpdateModel`method doesn't work too.

But if I remove the ErrorMessage arguments from the Required validation attribute in the Person class (i.e. leaving it just as [Required]), then the test passes.

So I don't know why `UpdateModel` doesn't validate the globalized Person model when I call the Create action method from the test case.

Answer (score 0):

I'm happy to see you are writing unit tests for your code :)

First, why don't you just pass `Person` in the first place, do you really need `FormCollection`?

```
[TestMethod]
void Create_DoesNotCreatePerson_WhenEmailIsEmpty()
{
    // arrange
    FormCollection person = new FormCollection() { { "Email", string.Empty } };
    PersonController controller = new PersonController();
    controller.ControllerContext = new ControllerContext();

    // third, you might need to add this (haven't tested this)
    controller.ModelState.AddModelError("Email", "fakeError");

    // act
    controller.Create(person);

    // assert
    Assert.IsFalse(controller.ModelState.IsValid);
}
```

**Fourth and most important**. I dont' think you should test like this. You want to test the outcome for different scenarios. That means you want to test the return value for the method. When you say `Assert.IsFalse(controller.ModelState.IsValid);` you basically say you don't trust Microsoft's code and you want to test their code. I can assure you they have unit tests on their code and you do not need to test it again ;)

Instead, test what view is returned and what object is returned from the action result. Here is a complete article for how to unit test this -> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg416511(VS.98).aspx (See "Creating a test for retrieving contacts"). Hope this helps!

EDIT (Answer to comments):

Sory for the long response time.

I removed to "second".

If you want to to test the real production code, you want to do integration tests, not unit tests. If unit tests is what you want I recommend you to follow my solution proposal, otherwise create integration tests. I don't know how to convince you more then I've tried so read more and from several sources and I think you will agree later on how to do unit testing in this case :)

Good luck!

Comment: First, I tried using Person, but validation isn't performed when the action method is called from a unit test and not by the Action Invoker as it would be on a real HTTP request. So I use a FormCollection instead of Person, and perform validation explicitly within the action method using UpdateModel.

Comment: Second, note that FormCollection is actually a NameValueCollection, and the inner {"Email", string.Empty} constructs a name-value pair, therefore the syntax is correct.

Comment: Third, I don't think to be correct of explicitly adding a model error in the unit test, because validations are made in production code. It would be best to simply create a Person with an invalid Email value and let the production code to perform validation.

Comment: Fourth, I don't think Assert.IsFalse(controller.ModelState.IsValid) is testing for Microsoft's code. If that were the case, the statement would be in the action part. The assertion only makes sure that my validation code of Person is actually working. In this case, if the assertion is false, I know that Person is not being created.

Comment: Hi, I added an EDIT, Did you test any of my suggestions?